# Problems with JDBC Java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a table in PostgreSQL 8.4:

```
DROP TABLE filedata_temp;

CREATE TABLE filedata_temp
(
num serial NOT NULL,
id integer,
kadnum character(25),
deleted character(3),
the_geom geometry,
status_id integer,
CONSTRAINT filedata_temp_pkey PRIMARY KEY (num)
)
WITH (
OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE filedata_temp OWNER TO postgres;
```

Simple data:

[image]

In java i do:

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            Connection ce= null;
          ce = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgis","postgres","123456");
          Statement se = null;
          se = ce.createStatement();
Integer idn=null;
System.out.println("idnnull= "+idn);
ResultSet id=se.executeQuery("SELECT num FROM filedata_temp ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 1");
    while(id.next()){
        idn=id.getInt("num");
        System.out.println("query= "+idn);
    }
    if(idn==null){
        idn=1;
    }
ce.close();
se.close();
System.out.println("idn= "+idn);
```

And in console i get this:

```
idnnull= null
idn= 1
```

So i not get a `System.out.println("query= "+idn);` in console. Its mean that ResultSet is empty. But if i make this query in PostgreSQL i get a normal response. Whats wrong?

Comment: What is that `LIMIT` you have used for, at the end of your Query?

Comment: Apparently your result set returns nothing. Did you commit your inserts into the table from the other session? Did you double check that you are connected to localhost in your Java program?

Comment: A connect to DB works fine. And i see a data i base.

Comment: Have you trimmed out the exception handling in your listing? If so, add it back in so that it paints a true picture of what you are running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result Set documentation says that method next returns true if the new current row is valid or false if there are no more rows.

So query result is not ok. Check your database connection, maybe you are connected to some other database which has empty table filedata_temp or some related problem.

Comment: I think connection is okey couse in previous classes all works fine.

Comment: Than just execute that code chunk in debug mode and you will be able to see if Result Set has data as you expected.

Comment: Most likely your changes weren't committed, so the Java connection didn't see the data you add through the admin tool.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

In above program change query to "SELECT * FROM filedata_temp" & change id.getInt to id.getObject.
See if you are atleast getting something with this query. If this gives all columns in your tables, then your connection, database, tables everything is fine.

Then next you change query to "SELECT num FROM filedata_temp" & use id.getObject. See if you are now able to get value of num for all rows.

If this works then add order by clause. When this works, then go for limit & other things.